# How to get value of another input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to find the value of text field using `onblur()` in next input field.

I tried:

```
function get_value() {

  var inv_nrs;
  inv_nrs = document.getElementsByTagName('text1').value;
  alert(inv_nrs);   
}
```

text1 is name of input which I am trying to get value.
 
text2 is name of input where `onblur()` is triggered.

Comment: getElementsByName() ???

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements, not a single element. You have to index it to access each element of the collection.

Comment: The same thing is true of `getElementsByName`, which is probably the function you want here. `getElementsByTagName('text1')` looks for elements like `<text1>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. To get elements by their `name` attribute, use `document.getElementsByName()`, not `document.getElementsByTagName`.
2. Since these functions return a collection, not a single element, you have to index them to get a specific element.

So the function should be:

```
function get_value() {

    var inv_nrs;
    inv_nrs = document.getElementsByName('text1')[0].value;
    alert(inv_nrs); 
}
```

Comment: ohh, thnks...  it works. bt what is [0], without it i can't get output

Comment: [0] is the index number. getElementsByName returns a list of elements. Let's suppose you had several inputs with the name 'text1' then [0] is the first input found, [1] the second input found, [2] the third input found etc

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple snippet which illustrates a way to do this.
*(You may wish to use `alert` in place of `console.log`)*

```js
document.getElementById("text2").onblur = function() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("text1").value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" value="123" />
<input type="text" id="text2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you search with tagname then you need to insert a tagname:**

> document.getElementsByTagName('input')[whole_number].value which also
>   returns a live HTMLCollection

Eg.  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value; ,**if this is the first textbox in your page.**

**You can get the value of an html element also on different ways:**

> document.getElementsByName('text1')[whole_number].value which also
>   returns a live NodeList
>
> Eg. document.getElementsByName("searchTsxt")[0].value; if this is the
>   first textbox with name 'searchtext' in your page.

**You can also get element by Id:**

> document.getElementById('IDHere').value to get the value of desired
>   box

**You can also get it by way of Classname:**

> Use  document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')[whole_number].value
>   which returns a Live HTMLCollection

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an element with id = "text1" or real name = "text1"?
At least if it's their id try `getElementById("text1")`, that returns one single element. If you talking about the name-attribute, take `getElementByName("text1")`, this may return more than one element (if there are more then one with the same name).

Comment: name of my input feild

Answer (score 0):

i think you want this???

```js
function get_value() 
{

var inv_nrs;
inv_nrs = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
 document.getElementById('txt2').value=inv_nrs;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" >
<input type="text" id="txt2" onblur="get_value()">
```